# arcpy.Describe and "in_memory": works with small feature (500 polygons) but returns "in_memory\xxx" does not exist" with large (200,000)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.7, in-memory, ioerror

I'm attempting to run 'arcpy.Describe()' on an object saved 'in_memory', following 'arcpy.Intersect_analysis'.

My script works with small multi-part polygon features (500 polygons) but then returns "IOError: "in_memory\int_fc" does not exist" when using larger ones (200k polygons).

```
# Import packages
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Overwrite existing datasets
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Environment
env.workspace = "C:/Users/xxx/ZMB_buf.gdb"

# Intersect to find overlaps in in_feat
arcpy.Intersect_analysis("in_feat", r"in_memory\int_fc")

# Describe OIDFieldName
oid_field = arcpy.Describe(r"in_memory\int_fc").OIDFieldName
print(oid_field)
```

I'd be happy to share the data if useful for debugging. I'm using ArcMap 10.7.1 and Python 2.7., on a 32 GB RAM laptop.

(Incidentally, I'm trying to run a larger function for exploding overlapping polygons: [Exploding overlapping to new non-overlapping polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32217/exploding-overlapping-to-new-non-overlapping-polygons) This function runs fine, but takes a long time, when using objects saved in local locations. However, it fails - for the same reason as above - when using 'in_memory', which I hoped would be quicker.)

Comment: 200k polygons is an awful lot for a 32-bit app that can only use 800-900Mb of RAM. Have you tried using Pro?

Comment: `in_memory` isn't a miracle solution -- It should only be used sparingly, on smaller tables. There's definitely a law of diminishing returns here.  Just use file geodatabase on an SSD.

Comment: I agree with @Vince `in_memory` is great for small datasets. When you need to do large amounts of processing then writing locally to a file geodatabase is the best solution. Don't use shapefiles as you need to ensure spatial indices exist; they are automatic with file geodatabases. Also it appears you are intersecting the layer on itself and that will likely generate millions of sliver polygons so you might "only have 200K" going in but you could have millions coming out of such an operation.

Comment: It might be worth looking into [Background Geoprocessing (64-bit) - ArcMap | Documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm) if you are stuck with ArcMap.

Comment: Just to extend what others have already said... avoid the "in_memory" workspace, and instead use `arcpy.env.scratchGDB` (or similar) for temporary data sets.  You may want to delete your datasets from the fGDB when you're finished with them (either as part of the script, or manually).